# Linked-list node delete function

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes, python-3.5

I've been asked to implement a Node delete function where i delete 1 node

why is my Node delete deleting entire list?.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
        self.next=None
        self.prev=None

class List(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None # start of list
        self.tail=None # end of list

    def insert(self,n,x):
        if n!=None:
            x.next=n.next
            n.next=x
            x.prev=n
            if x.next!=None:
                x.next.prev=x
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=self.tail=x
            x.prev=x.next=None
        elif self.tail==n:
            self.tail=x

    def display(self):
        values=[]
        n=self.head
        while n!=None:
            values.append(str(n.value))
            n=n.next
        print ("List: ",",".join(values))

    def deleteNode (self,n):
        if n.prev!=None:
            n.prev.next = n.next
        else:
            self.head = n.next

        if n.next  != None:
            n.next.prev = n.prev
        else:
            self.tail = n.prev

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listofnodes=List()
    listofnodes.insert(None, Node(4))
    listofnodes.insert(l.tail,Node(6))
    listofnodes.insert(l.head,Node(8))
    listofnodes.insert(l.head,Node(5))
    listofnodes.insert(l.head,Node(9))
    listofnodes.insert(l.head,Node(10))
    listofnodes.deleteNode(Node(8)) # I want to delete Node 8 from listofnodes
    listofnodes.display()
```

before the node delete is called the whole list displays, after i run it shows no elements

Any ideas?

Comment: try `listofnodes.deleteNode(Node(8))` (too many arguments here)

Comment: I've sorted that bit but the function deletes all nodes rather than the one selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

`listofnodes.deleteNode(l,Node(8))`

you are passing 2 argument, with a third one (the `self` in the declaration) passed implicitly

You declare the method as

`def deleteNode (self,n):`

so it accept only one parameter (n)

Comment: Thanks mate, i couldn't see it for some reason.

Comment: ive sorted that bit now but the delete function is deleting the entire list rather than the node selected?

Comment: Give me positive rating! i need it to get unblocked haha